# Derive function reference from a generic extension function/method in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, extension-methods

Is there a way to get a function reference to a generic extension function/method in Kotlin?

```kotlin
class C
fun <T> C.f1(t: T) = TODO()
val f1Ref1 = C::f1<T> // Compiler error
val f1Ref2 = C::f1 // Compiler error
```

But this is fine:

```kotlin
fun C.f2(i: Int) = TODO()
val f2Ref = C::f2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify the type explicitly

```
val f1Ref1: C.(Int) -> Unit = C::f1
```

Comment: This is related to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver.